# Is it common for professional drywallers to tape narrow corners, but not mud over the tape if it's going to be covered with moulding?

Tags: drywall, mudding, taping

Sorry to spam SE with questions relating to a job done by a company I hired to finish the project in my room, but some things seem very questionable to me.

In the below pics you will see a narrow corner that's just smaller than the width of your average-sized piece of moulding.  As you can see, they taped the corner and even applied what appears to be a partial coat of mud.

My initial thought was that they simply overlooked it due to the tiny amount of area between the door opening and wall.  However, when I addressed this with the superintendent and project manager when they came to my house in response to my complaints about the quality, they replied, "Your moulding will go over that, so they didn't finish that section since it's going to be hidden anyway."  Being the pushover that I am (not that it helps any that I am a novice DIY'er), I bought it.  However, I can't help but think they were just giving me any excuse to keep me from having their crew make another trip out to actually finish it.  Having thought more about it, I wonder why they even taped and partially mudded that narrow section in the first place.  Did I get taken for a complete idiot?

**Edit 11/28/2012** No one has yet answered this question or come out and said it, but, judging by the comments section, it seems that everyone's thinking that this area should have been completely finished.  As Matthew also stated, you don't know how wide the moulding is going to be.  By shirlock's comment, if it *were* a snug fit, no taping would have been needed.  As I understand it, taping is mainly to prevent the cracking of compound between joints (please correct me if I'm wrong) and has nothing to do with structural integrity.  If that's the case, their response of "we only partially finished it because it's going to be covered by moulding anyway" makes no sense since they wouldn't have even needed to put down any tape in the first place.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: They taped it because it's a seam, and all seams must be taped.  The better question is, why did they end up with a tiny sliver of a piece like that anyway? And if it's going to be covered, why did they even bother putting anything there at all?

Comment: I think we've already established that your pro's aren't so pro..

Comment: They have no idea how large or small your door casing is going to be.....

Comment: ABSOLUTE BS..PERIOD.   You got taken to the cleaners. these Bozos haven't got a clue. Shoddy workmanship at best.  Sorry for your pain.

Comment: The more I look at your pics, the madder it makes me. If the rock had been cut and hung correctly, it would have been fairly snug to the door frame and not required any taping at all. Since they had to tape means they left too big a gap. Simply shameful and the foreman who you are dealing with is an A**. Please whip me if i ever tried to pull that crap on my customers.

Comment: I hung the drywall myself and there are 1/4" gaps between all sheets, but that's by design so that they could filled with acoustical caulk.  Still, is there any reason why they would have taped and then stopped finishing on account of the fact that "I am going to cover it anyway" or did they most likely forget to finish it all the way?

Comment: Sorry, but I am going to have to ignore any future posts of yours oscilatingcretin, they just piss me off too much.  The Three Stooges would do a better job AND you will get a show.  These guys should of been kicked off the job long ago.

Comment: I can't decide if you're making a music/AV room or a kill room...

Comment: You don't put a drywall joint near the corner of a door or window, it will crack from the motion. This was sloppy to have the joint there in the first place, and the laziness of the taping just draws attention to their sloppy workmanship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would not lose a lot of sleep over this.  The molding will probably cover it up.  If not have the contractor make the necessary adjustments.  Tape would still be needed for the seam that is above the door that we can't see in the pictures.  Do you feel that part of the seam was properly done?  There is also an indentation on the edge of wall board for the tape that might have been easier to fill with tape instead of just joint compound that shrinks and could crack.